# NSPredicate filter by NSDate in custom object with [NSDate date]

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I have an `NSMutableArray` of Model objects.

Each Model Object has a startTime property of `NSDate` type

I would like to using `NSPredicate` to filter the `NSMutableArray`.
I want an array with items older then now and one with items newer then now.

This is the code im using but the filtered arrays are empty. I do make sure there are items in the primary array im filtering from.

```
    NSPredicate *pastPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(startTime < %@)", [NSDate date]];
    NSPredicate *futurePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(startTime >= %@)", [NSDate date]];

    self.pastReservations = [self.reservations filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pastPredicate];
    self.futureReservations = [self.reservations filteredArrayUsingPredicate:futurePredicate];
```

Can you guys let me know if you know what I'm doing wrong? I dont think I should have to use a block for predicate using a built in type.

Comment: The code seems fine to me, add a breakpoint before filtering the array and print the objects contained in self.reservations, I suspect that the array is empty.

Comment: yeah all my dates were nil because of a parsing error.

Comment: @adrian.coroian: If your problem is solved, you can post your own answer and mark it as accepted, so that other people see that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was correct. There was code before that was not working right and self.reservations was empty like Ramy Al Zuhouri said.

Answer (score 0):

Why not this way:

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];

for(YourModelObject* obj in self.reservations) {

    NSDate* objectDate = obj.date; 

    //if negative, "now" is earlier, so >= 0 is past 
    if([now timeIntervalSinceDate:objectDate] >= 0) {
        [self.pastReservations addObject:obj];
    } else {
        [self.futureReservations addObject:obj];
    }

}
```

Comment: look how much nicer my way is :)